# List of simple products linked to configurable product

Tags: magento, combinations

Is there a way to show simple products and have them grouped in 1 product, so when you click on any simple product it link you to grouped product where you can pick different colour/sizes.

In short:

```
skirt blue    ->|
skirt red     ->|----> big product with blue/red/white option
skirt white   ->|
```

You pick from simple products (one color) and you link to grouped / configurable) product that connects those simple products rather then going to check details of a simple product

Answer (score 0):

You can get the configurable product ids from simple using below code

```
$simpleProductId = 'Your Simple Product Id'; 
$parentIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
    ->getParentIdsByChild($simpleProductId);
```